# load USB dev on Slackware 14.2

Tags: linux, slackware, dvb

I'm trying to setup a dvb device on Slackware 14.2

```
bash-4.3# lsusb | grep YUAN
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1164:7efd YUAN High-Tech Development Co., Ltd

bash-4.3# udevadm info --path=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
N: bus/usb/001/003
E: BUSNUM=001
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/003
E: DEVNUM=003
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MEDIA_PLAYER=zte_score
E: ID_MODEL=STK7700D
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=STK7700D
E: ID_MODEL_ID=7efd
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=YUANRD_STK7700D_0000000001
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0000000001
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
E: ID_VENDOR=YUANRD
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=YUANRD
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=YUAN High-Tech Development Co., Ltd
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=1164
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=2
E: PRODUCT=1164/7efd/100
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TAGS=:udev-acl:
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=15164626
```

I created the  following files (commented out line failed)

```
bash-4.3# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules        
#ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", RUN+="firmware --firmware=/lib/firmware/dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw  --devpath=$env{DEVPATH}"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe dvb-usb-dib0700"
#KERNEL=="dvb0.dvr*",      ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", NAME="dvb/adapter0/dvr%n",      SYMLINK+="dvb/adapter0/dvr%n"
#KERNEL=="dvb0.demux*",    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", NAME="dvb/adapter0/demux%n",    SYMLINK+="dvb/adapter0/demux%n"
#KERNEL=="dvb0.frontend*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", NAME="dvb/adapter0/frontend%n", SYMLINK+="dvb/adapter0/frontend%n"
#KERNEL=="dvb0.audio*",    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", NAME="dvb/adapter0/audio%n",    SYMLINK+="dvb/adapter0/audio%n"
#KERNEL=="dvb0.ca*",       ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd"  NAME="dvb/adapter0/ca%n",       SYMLINK+="dvb/adapter0/ca%n"
#KERNEL=="dvb0.osd*",      ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", NAME="dvb/adapter0/osd%n",      SYMLINK+="dvb/adapter0/osd%n"
#KERNEL=="dvb0.net*",      ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", NAME="dvb/adapter0/net%n",      SYMLINK+="dvb/adapter0/net%n"
#KERNEL=="dvb0.video*",    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1164", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7efd", NAME="dvb/adapter0/video%n",    SYMLINK+="dvb/adapter0/video%n"

bash-4.3# echo 1164 7efd > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/dvb_usb_dib0700/new_id
bash-4.3# cat /etc/modprobe.d/dvb.conf
options dvb-usb-dib0700 force_lna_activation=1
```

But I still have not got a /dev/dvb directory.
Where do I go wrong?